# React.js - Styled components - center image in direct div parent with other objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I understand that question looks pretty easy, but I haven't found anything helping me.

I have an image inside a div, and I want that image to be centered in that div even if I add, for example, a text.

Here is some code and images to better understand that problem :

If I only have my image in my div (with solid border), all is well :

```
<div>
    <img height = '75px' width = '75px' src={USDCoin}/> 
</div>
```

[image]

But adding a text, I can't figure out how to keep the image in the center of the div (well aligned with the grey lines) and the text below that :

```
<div>
    <img height = '75px' width = '75px' src={USDCoin}/> 
    test
</div>
```

[image]

Here is a full example :

```
<div style = {{display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
height: 90%;
width: 100%;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;}}>
   <Line/>
   <div>
      <img height = '75px' width = '75px' src={USDCoin}/>   
   </div>   
   <Line/>
   <Line/>
   <div>
      <img height = '75px' width = '75px' src={USDCoin}/>   
      test
   </div>   
   <Line/>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your precious help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` to do this very easily.
I've created an example here for you (doesn't include styled-components but your issue is not the styled components anyway) https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-night-7859bz

Comment: Hello Christian ! 
Thank you for your answer.

However, that doesn't respond to my interrogation : I would like the image centered in the div, even with a text below it. Hence, NOT like my last picture, where the image is not centered but touching the top of the div (just like the example you gave)

Comment: Aaa i see you want the image to have the same baseline, when there is text or not.
It would be helpful if you could provide a working example of your problem.
I'm not sure how it's positioned on the line you have in your pictures

Comment: I added a little something : just a bigger container :)

Comment: Hmm I don't know how this would be possible without knowing the height of the text. Or if it would work for you to add the same text above the image and just visually hide it with `visibility: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

you should use flex-direction: column;

```
import { React } from "react";
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          height: "90%",
          width: "100px",
          border: "2px solid",
          justifyContent: "center",
          margin: "0 auto",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <img
            height="75px"
            width="75px"
            src={
              "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1638913662252-70efce1e60a7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
            }
          />
        </div>

        <div>test</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```